# Use Hibernate with Spring Boot, Wildfly and Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to understand how to write a simple method to retrieve data from a DB without success.
I'm using Spring Boot 2.1, Hibernate (provided by Spring Boot), Wildfly 14 and Oracle 12.

Connection with the DB seems to work using datasources on standalone.xml (read by the application.properties file). My problem is that if I try to use EntityManager, EntityManagerFactory or Repositories they are always null and I cannot understand why.

Probably I'm missing something on the configuration. My application.properties is:

```
# Datasource
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/TestDB

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

I defined a simple Entity like this

```
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@Column
private int myId;
private int anotherData;

... (getters and setters) ...

}
```

Now I don't know what to do.
I created a DAO class with some Autowired variables (like EntityManagerFactory) but they're always null.

How can I manipulate my entities?

Comment: You had miss something, the interest of Spring-Boot to avoid the Application Server (like WildFly). Have a look on the examples from http://spring.io

Comment: Spring Boot can use it's embedded AS but it works even with other ASs. The interest should be to make easier configure an application.

Comment: YEs but it's totally usless to use Spring-Boot inside an AS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foud the solution looking at [this](https://github.com/robsonapsilva/spring-boot-wildfly) example.